# Is it possible to trigger #warning during link time?

Tags: c, gcc

I am writing some modules in C (gcc) that will call functions outside of a module. For testing purposes I implement dummy functions that just print their arguments. Someone else will then implement the real functions. Right now I am implementing them as weak symbols, so that they can be overriden by "real" functions during link time.
**Is there a way that I could see a warning whenever my weak symbol is linked?** (like #warning during compile time) I would like to know when a particular function is not implemented and a dummy one is linked instead.

I already know the alternatives - pass an struct of function pointers during initialization of my module and use function pointers inside my module, use a lot of #ifdefs or modify the build process to link only one version.

Comment: Don't implement a "dummy" version and the program won't link unless the function is implemented. This is how one normally deals with situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some [`#pragma message`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) gcc directive:

```
/* dummy foo function is just for testing purpose, so is only defined in debug version. */
#ifdef _DEBUG

/* foo is your dummy function for testing */
int foo()
{
    #pragma message "Warning: using dummy version of foo function"
    return 0;
}
#endif
```